# How to compress quality of conversion JPG to WebP in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert the jpg images into new generation WebP format. I used PIL for that and everything working perfectly!
But my problem is when the program compresses a JPG file which is 134KB and when it converted into WebP it became 108KB.

How I can shorten the size of the WebP image ?, I want to compress the quality.

**My code looks like this:**

```
from PIL import Image


image = Image.open('my-image.jpg')
image = image.convert('RGB')
image.save('my-image.jpg.webp', 'webp')
```

Does anybody know how we can again decrease the size of the converted WebP images?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the quality parameter  while saving the image.

```
image.save('my-image.jpg.webp', 'webp', optimize = True, quality = 10)
```

Save the picture with desired quality. To change the quality of image, set the quality variable at your desired level, The more the value of quality variable
and lesser the compression

Comment: Just adding that quality goes from 0 - 100 inclusive. i find 85 barely noticable with still huge file size savings.

Answer (score 0):

Converting JPG to WebP using OpenCV in Python.

```
import cv2

jpg_file_path = 'input_image.jpg'
webp_file_path = 'output_image.webp'

# Read the JPG image
jpg_img = cv2.imread(jpg_file_path)

# Save the image in JPG format with specific quality
cv2.imwrite(webp_file_path, jpg_img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY), 80])
```

In the last line, the desired WebP quality has been set to 80. You may change it to required quality. You can choose a quality in the range [0, 100]. Lower the quality, higher the compression, and lower the output WebP image size.

Reference: [Python OpenCV – Convert JPG to WebP](https://pythonexamples.org/python-opencv-convert-jpg-to-webp/)